# Repeat-until or equivalent loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner in Python programming. I am trying to work on this algorithm that finds convex hull using Graham's scan method. However, in the pseudocode, there is a `repeat ... until` loop, which I could not figure out a way to write it in Python.

How do I write a `repeat ... until` loop in Python?

Comment: as a side-note, google redirects to here when asking repeat-until equivalent. So, in other languages, if exists, `do-while` is  `repeat-until` **except that _condition_ is logically inverted**.

Comment: There is another difference. In `repeat-until`, the condition is evaluated at the end of the loop. So at least one iteration of the loop will always be executed before the end is reached and condition is evaluated.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
REPEAT
    ...
UNTIL cond
```

Is equivalent to

```
while True:
    ...
    if cond:
        break
```

Comment: `if cond` is wrong. It has to be `if not cond` for Python or `if !(cond)` for Java, C, C++

Comment: @snr, both loops exit when `cond` is true

Comment: The previous two comments seem contradictory and the first one has an upvote. Which is correct? Perhaps and example would help to clarify?

Comment: @Robin the confusion is a good illustration of the common confusion between `while cond do {}` and `repeat {} until cond` loops. A while loop continues *as long as* its condition is `True`, a repeat loop continues *until* its condition is `True`. @snr is wrong, but it's a common mistake. Compare: `while must_continue: command` and `while True: command; if not must_continue: break`. You could do the opposite with `repeat`, but you never see those examples, because languages with `repeat` typically also have `while`.

Comment: @Robin: first comment is indeed wrong.

Comment: The answer is correct. Doing while True and then breaking on 'condition' is the same as repeat until 'condition'. Adding a not is not needed here!