# Until statement/loop python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there an `until` statement or loop in python? This does not work:

```
x = 10
list = []
until x = 0:
    list.append(raw_input('Enter a word: '))
    x-=1
```

Comment: See also: [Is there a “do … until” in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662161/is-there-a-do-until-in-python) and [Repeat-Until loop in python or equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758807/repeat-until-loop-in-python-or-equivalent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is a `while x1 != x2` loop.

Thus, your code becomes:

```
x = 10
lst = [] #Note: do not use list as a variable name, it shadows the built-in
while x != 0:
    lst.append(raw_input('Enter a word: '))
    x-=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while x != 0:
    #do stuff
```

This will run until x == 0

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to count how many times you're looping unless you're doing something with that variable.  Instead, you can use a `for` loop that will fire up to 10 times instead:

```
li = []
for x in range(10):
    li.append(raw_input('Enter a word: '))
```

As an aside, don't use `list` as a variable name, as that masks the actual `list` method.

Answer (score 1):

Python emulates *until* loops with the [`iter(iterable, sentinel)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) idiom:

```
x = 10
list = []
for x in iter(lambda: x-1, 0):
    list.append(raw_input('Enter a word: '))
```

- I was forced to construct a trivial *lambda* for demonstration purposes; here a simple `range()` would suffice, as as @Makoto suggested.