# Paging through a url response without knowing the total page number, stop when page is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a response that I need to page through but it doesn't have the total page number available. How can I go about paging through the response? For instance lets say I have this response:

```
response = requests.get(url='test.com', headers=headers, page=1)
```

and I want to do something like this where I get each page of the response's results into the **items** list, but as I mentioned I don't know what my total_pages are, so how would get each pages response and stop when the page is empty?

```
items = []
for page_number in range(1, total_pages + 1): 
     items = items + requests.get(url='test.com', headers=headers, page=page_number)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat-until or equivalent loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758807/repeat-until-or-equivalent-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop.

```
items = []
page_nr = 1
while True:
    page = requests.get(url='test.com', headers=headers, page=page_nr)
    is_empty = # ... your code here to check if the page is empty.
    if is_empty:
        break
    # ... add stuff from page to items.
    page_nr += 1
```

Comment: Can also add that the user should check for a 404 status code: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes

Comment: `page_nr` and `page_number` should presumably match, and be incremented?

Comment: @SimonBrahan Woopsie, fixed.